# Is it a bad idea to disable portreserve?

Tags: scientific-linux

```
chkconfig portreserve off
```

So that portreserve will not run at next boot. Can any bad things happen? I mean I think it's better to use "KISS" so that minimal applications will listen on 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the discussion that led to `portreserve`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=103401), you probably can do without if you don't use `cupsd` and don't experience random port binding failures on boot due to a misbehaving `portmap`.  (This implies that you most certainly can do without if you can do without `portmap`.)

I don't quite understand your reasoning with binding to address `0.0.0.0`, as it's about port numbers as far as I understood.

[In the end, `portreserve` doesn't add that much bloat to the system](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=portreserve.git;a=blob;f=src/portreserve.c;h=18bff9ccae37b38c3eee3c76d15e75ddffa11b50;hb=HEAD), [while it gains you some predictability on boot-up](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=portreserve.git;a=blob;f=README;h=ac5319cea2bdbd2a917596a86a781278532cb923;hb=HEAD)

Comment: from my understanding, if a program listens on 0.0.0.0 then that means that if there is no firewall, then the program could be reached from "outside" the pc.